# WPF WebBrowser - catch error StatusCode

Tags: wpf, browser, http-status-codes

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser control, and I would like to redirect to a custom error page if the page I try to navigate to returns an error (404 or other statuscode).

Is there a way to do it, maybe in the "navigated" event ? I tried it but the WebResponse is emtpy...

No idea ?

[image]